# Report Footer On ReportViewer

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

It ´s a real pleassure to be part of this great community.

My questions it's that.. How can a I set a Report Footer (Information that just appear on the last page of the report ) in reportViewer?.

cause when I set Page footer it appear on every single page of my report, but I need the information only once, on the last page of the report.

VisualStudio TeamSystem 2008.
C#
windows XP Profesional SP3

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can insert a rectangle to your report footer and put all of your footer to that. after that write an expression for its visibility. you should use 
`Globals!PageNumber` and `Globals!TotalPages` for this. if this two property equals then you set visibility to true.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much.. It work real good... I'm only have to control just the layout cause when it is not visible..some information take the place of the square but it is fine.. thank Masoud..

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn your footer text to an expresion like this

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber<>Globals!TotalPages,"","My footer text")
```